# How do I open a case that started more than twenty years ago?

Tags: civicase, dates

We have one client whose case started 25 years ago.

This falls out of range of the allowable open case date range and produces this message:
[image]

Is there a way to expand/change this date range?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can expand this range in `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences`.

Change the `start Offset` of `activityDateTime` class to 30.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra Purohit! I changed the start offset to 30 and it worked.